# CSS format carousel issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm woring in this carousel, i'm using bootstram, and OWL Carousel : http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel

what i need to do is, make the clicked button taller, and in front of the image, like in the attached images.

HTML

```
<!-- owl carousol start -->
<div id="demo">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">


                <div id="sync1" class="owl-carousel">
                    <div class="item">
                        <h1>Atentos, despiertos, <br/> llenos de energía</h1>
                        <img src="images/slider.png"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <h1>Atentos, despiertos, <br/> llenos de energía</h1>
                        <img src="images/slider.png"/></div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <h1>Atentos, despiertos, <br/> llenos de energía</h1>
                        <img src="images/slider.png"/></div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <h1>Atentos, despiertos, <br/> llenos de energía</h1>
                        <img src="images/slider.png"/></div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <h1>Atentos, despiertos, <br/> llenos de energía</h1>
                        <img src="images/slider.png"/></div>

                </div>

                <div id="sync2" class="owl-carousel">
                    <div class="item"><a href="#"><h1>Un nuevo amanecer</h1></a></div>
                    <div class="item"><a href="#"><h1>Conoce Expo Digital</h1></a></div>
                    <div class="item"><a href="#"><h1>Expo Priority</h1></a></div>
                    <div class="item"><a href="#"><h1>Expo Gold</h1></a></div>
                    <div class="item"><h1>Expo at work</h1></div>
                </div>

             
            </div>

        </div>
        
    </div>

</div>
```

And the CSS

```
#sync1 .item{
    background: #0c83e7;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    color: #FFF;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-align: center;



}
#sync2 .item{
    background: #fff;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    color: #FFF;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius:0px;
    margin-left:-5px;
    border-left:1px solid #91c04e;

    border: 1px solid red;

}
#sync2 .item:nth-child(6){
    border:0px;
}
#sync2 .item h1{
  font-size: 18px;
    font-family: HelveticaNeueLight;
    color:#9ac55d ;
}
#sync2 .synced .item{
  background: #9ac55d;
    color: #fff;
}
#sync2 .synced .item h1{
    color: #fff;
    font-family: HelveticaNeueLight;
}
#sync1 .item h1{

    font-family: HelveticaNeueLight;
    font-style: italic;
    position: absolute;
    width: 98%;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 48px;
}
#sync1 .item img{

    width: 100%;
    


    
}

.owl-item .item img{
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;

}

.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-buttons div{
    display:none;


}


.owl-wrapper{
    width:1000px;


}


.owl-theme .owl-controls{
    margin:0px;
}
#sync2{
    
    z-index:9999999999999;
    margin-top:0px;
}
#sync2 .synced .item{
    
    color:#1c6f42;
    border-right:1px solid #91c04e;

    height: 55px;
    margin: -10px 0px 0px 0px;
    z-index: 99999999;
}

#sync2 .item{
    
    color:#91c04e;
    height:45px;

}

#demo .full_width{
    
    max-width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;

}

#sync2 .item a:active{
    
    color:red;
    height:55px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 10px 1px 1px 1px;
    z-index: 9999999;   

}
```

What i need is to get this button taller and in fron of the main image.
that's why i'm coming here, because i had not found a solution in other palce.

This is the way i'm doing it:

[image]

and this is the way i need it working.

[image]

So i'm trying a lot of cases, but i still don't found the way to do it.

thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

In css3 you have the scale propertie :

```
.item:hover{
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

will make the hovered item 2 times bigger.

```
 .item a:active{
      transform: scale(2);
    }
```

Feel free to ask if needed

Comment: Thank you so much, but it doens't fix the issue

Comment: So I did not get what you need.

Comment: thank you, i need to make the button selected bigger, like in the second image, that button is bigger because it was clicked!, but thats just the psd. 
In the first image i'm trying to do, but i just move the letters, i don't move the button or make a little bit taller!

Comment: So if I understand well you need the kind of thing I've did when selected instead of hover, righ?

Comment: thank you!, yes, i did tried in active, but still not working, i just what to make the selected item taller, like in the first image!

Comment: if you want to make it work with active the .item element must be a link <a>

Comment: The other solution would be to make it work with javascript. I've made a change to my answer to make it work on the child link. try it and let me know

Comment: thank you so much @Hugz, it works, not the way i was specting!, i'm trying to make it taller, and cover a little bit of the image with the button